# Need help in how to use applyMap in my below code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm using a code and generates an output as below.

**CODE**

```
User_info = {
    1: ["Rita","delhi",47,47,38],
    2: ["Sita","DElhi",49,28,40],
    3: ["geeta","Mumbai",38,50,38],
    4: ["Geeta","MUMBAI",28,26,44],
    5: ["GEETA","CHENNAI",30,36,36],
    6: ["SITA","chennai",37,28,34]
}

print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format('Name', 'Location', 'W1', 'W2', 'W3')) 

for key, value in User_info.items(): 
    name, location, w1, w2, w3 = value 
    print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format(name, location, w1*1.609, w2*1.609, w3*1.609))
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

My Requirement is is would like to use **applymap function** to change the **Name** and **Location** column values to **upper**

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: What kind of type is the output? Is a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need print values:

```
for key, value in User_info.items(): 
    name, location, w1, w2, w3 = value 
    print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format(name.upper(), location.upper(), w1*1.609, w2*1.609, w3*1.609))
```